# Using Zookeeper or equivalent for .NET configuration management?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have a proprietary CMS that keeps a lot (20k lines) of configuration files on disk. I have quite a few nodes, all with the same configurations except for one or two elements that designate the node name and the IP.

Since this is proprietary I do not have a lot of leverage for going in and completely overhauling the configuration loading to look at an endpoint, though I might be able to be creative.

My questions are simple, but I do not know a better place to answer them:

1. Is this a use case for distributed configuration management like Zookeeper? Ideally I'd like to spin up a box and have it look for a service endpoint to load config files rather than have the config files deployed through source. This way I can update the configuration in one place, and have it replicate to all nodes without doing a full deployment.
2. Can Zookeeper (or equivalent) mimic a file system? Could I mount an NFS point and have it expose configuration as if they were files on the filesystem, even if these are symbolic constructs? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration use case seems more like a a job for chef, puppet or similar system. They will allow you to update the configuration in one place, keep them version controlled, and distribute them properly to all target nodes.

Zookeeper makes sense when your application/service needs to dynamically get fresh configuration data during live operation, and when multiple nodes in your system need the same consistent view of that data. If you don't have this requirements, Zookeeper might be too much of an overhead for just laying down mostly static config files on disk.

As for mimicking a filesystem, there is zkfuse which you could use to mount it. But again, it doesn't look like this is what you want. Zookeeper should not be used as an actual file system replacement or file distribution system. It is best for storing small bits of metadata that needs to be consistent across your distributed system.